# Ideals of non semi-simple group rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I worked for a long time on complex group rings and complex twisted group rings. In those cases the algebra is semi-simple and its structure is well understood from the decomposition to irreducible (projective in the twisted case) representations. For example

$$\mathbb{C}S_3\cong \mathbb{C}\oplus \mathbb{C}\oplus M_2(\mathbb{C}).$$

Now I am trying to deal with a non-simple case in which the group is non-commutative (in the commutative case it is much easier).

Now, I am stuck in the following example.

Let 
$$G=C_7\rtimes C_3,$$
where the action of $C_3$ on $C_7$ is by sending its generator $\sigma$ to $\sigma ^4$.

Describe (as best as you can) the ring structure of the group ring
$$\mathbb{F}_3G.$$

Here the group ring is not semi-simple. However, I am trying to find a maximal (length) chain of ideals $I_0,I_1,\ldots ,I_k$ such that
$$\{0\}=I_0\subseteq I_1 \subseteq I_2 \subseteq \ldots \subseteq I_k=\mathbb{F}_3G.$$

So far I made no progress.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It's not semisimple, but it is still quasi-Frobenius. Since I'm not super comfortable with semidirect products, my intuition about the structure breaks down a bit. You might be able to compute directly what its central idempotents are, and therefore come to the conclusion that it splits as Derek described. I'd hope that'd give some members of your chain, and maybe by then you'd see some dimensionality fact that would help you sort out if your chain is maximal or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand the explicit structure of group algebras like this, a useful idea is that of a skew group ring, which is a ring theoretic analogue of a semidirect product.

Let $G$ be a group acting by ring automorphisms on a ring $A$. Then the elements of the skew group ring $A\ast G$ are formal finite sums $\sum_{g\in G}a_gg$ with $a_g\in A$, with multiplication following from the rule that $gag^{-1}$ is the result of acting by $g$ on $a$, for $g\in G$ and $a\in A$. So, for example, if a group $G$ acts on another group $H$, inducing an action on the group algebra $kH$ for any field $k$, then the group algebra $k[H\rtimes G]$ of the semidirect product is the same as the skew group algebra $(kH)*G$.

Two special cases suffice to understand the group algebra of the question.

First, if $G$ acts trivially on a field $k$, then clearly $k\ast G$ is just the normal group algebra $kG$.

Second, if a finite group $G$ of order $n$ acts faithfully on a field $K$ with fixed field $k$, so $[K:k]=n$, then $K\ast G$ acts by $k$-linear endomorphisms on $K$ by 
$$\left(\sum_{g\in G}\lambda_gg\right)(\mu)=\sum_{g\in G}\lambda_gg(\mu),$$
inducing a map of $k$ algebras 
$$K\ast G\to\operatorname{End}_k(K)\cong M_n(k)$$
which is injective since the set of field automorphisms of a field $K$ is linearly independent over $K$, and therefore an isomorphism by considering dimensions.

Going back to the example in the question, $\mathbb{F}_3C_7\cong\mathbb{F}_3\times\mathbb{F}_{3^6}$ as $\mathbb{F}_3$-algebras (this follows from the fact that $\mathbb{F}_{3^6}$ is the smallest extension of $\mathbb{F}_3$ containing a primitive seventh root of $1$), and $C_3$ acts trivially on the first factor and faithfully on the second (with fixed field $\mathbb{F}_9$), so
$$\mathbb{F}_3[C_7\rtimes C_3]\cong (\mathbb{F}_3\ast C_3)\times(\mathbb{F}_{3^6}\ast C_3)
\cong\mathbb{F}_3C_3\times M_3(\mathbb{F}_9).$$

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about this topic, but I did a quick calculation in Magma on $A = {\mathbb F}_3G$. It appears to be a direct sum of a simple algebra of dimension $18$ and a uniserial algebra of dimension $3$ with $3$ trivial composition factors. If you do this over the field of order $9$, then the $18$-dimensional algebra splits into a direct sum of two $9$-dimensionals.

I am sure that an expert in modular representation theroy could explain all of this! The projective indecomposable modules consist of a $3$-dimensional module with three trivial consitutents and an irreducible $6$-dimensional modal that splits in half over ${\mathbb F}_9$.

Comment: Thanks a lot and +1. I am hoping somone can give a way to this without computer, since I wish to describe this objects for any groups of the form $C_q\rtimes C_p$.

Comment: Dear Derek : That's really cool! It's a great tragedy in my life that I've never had the time to pick up Magma. Might you be willing to share the code you used somehow? Perhaps as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/)? Regards

Comment: Unfortunately Magma is licensed software.